# Modifying textbox value after selection on second form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In FORM1, I have a textbox that has placeholder text. On click, a second form (FORM2) will pop up with a list of items to choose from. They choose their selection and press on SELECT and FORM2 closes and FORM1's textbox will populate with their selection from FORM2.

Here's what I have:

FORM1 -

```
    // Variables
    public string ID{ get; set; }

    private void openF2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FORM2 f2 = new FORM2();
        f2.Show();
        // updateText(); <-- when called through here, ID is still empty.
    }

    public void updateText()
    {
        textBox1.Text = ID;
        // textBox1.Refresh(); <-- I thought this would work
    }

    // Check if it did change
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

FORM2 -

```
    private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FORM1 f1= new FORM1();
        f1.ID = listOfChoices.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].ToString();
        f1.updateText();
        this.Close();
    }
```

When I walk-through the code, I see that ID is being set correctly and when FORM2 calls "updateText()" it sets the textbox1 value to ID and the textChanged function also runs, yet on the GUI, it's still empty.

Comment: You are updating a new instance of `Form1`, not the original instance that was running before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new instance of `Form1` from `Form2` and setting the property on it, but as soon as your `Form2` goes away, so does the instance that it created.

In your case, the easiest way to solve this problem is to show your `Form2` as a dialog - which means all execution on `Form1` pauses while it's active. Then, when `Form2` closes, you can still access the properties of it from `Form1` because execution on `Form1` picks up again right where it left off. This means that if we create a public property on `Form2` and set it to the value that the user chooses, we can access it later.

Here's one way to do it:

**Form2**

Let's create a public property called `ChosenItem` and we'll set it to the item that the user chooses:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string ChosenItem = "Some default text";

    private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChosenItem = listOfChoices.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].ToString();
        this.Close();
    }

    // Rest of form code omitted...
}
```

**Form1**

Launch `Form2` as a dialog and then set our value from the form after it closes:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void openF2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        textBox1.Text = f2.ChosenItem;
    }

    // Rest of form code omitted...
}
```